# Setting up Idempotency for Parse-Platform on k8s

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to enable the Idempotency options on a Parse-Platform server.
I've tried adding the following to my k8s config:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --idempotencyOptions
        - '{"paths":["classes/.*"], ttl: 30}'
```

I've also tried to add it to env vars (according to https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/7151 you have to write the json object as a string.

```
        env:
        - name: PARSE_SERVER_EXPERIMENTAL_IDEMPOTENCY_OPTIONS
          value: '{"paths":["classes/.*"], ttl: 30}'
```

No luck. The first option and I get an error/crash loop stating idempotencyOptions isn't valid. The second one, it boots up fine, but duplicates still occur even when the proper headers are added (`X-Parse-Request-Id`)

Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: For the first one, would you mind to share the code that you are using in order to get this arg and pass to Parse Server? Anyways, I believe the second one should work fine. Could you please provide more details on how you tested it and got duplicated values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, always good to double check your versions.

Both of these work, my Parse Server was 4.2.0. This feature was introduced in 4.3.0. Once I upgraded everything worked as intended.